# How can we redirect on click on href?

Tags: javascript, href

body tag: `<a href="javascript:gotoURL();">T&Cs</a>`

head tag:

```
function gotoURL() {

        window.location = 'someurl.html';

    }
```

Not working, any idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make a redirect page in jQuery/JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript)

Comment: Think about using `<a href='someurl.html' onclick="javascript:gotoURL();">` That way users can still right click and open in a new tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify the function:

```
function gotoURL() {
  window.location.href = "someurl.html";
}
```

Source: [How can I make a redirect page in jQuery/JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript)